# xrandr --pos not working for external monitor

Tags: display, multi-monitor, xrandr, resolution

I want my external 4k monitor on the left and my internal FHD laptop monitor on the right, scaled accordingly.

I have written a little script to help with that, and it worked on my previous machine. But now the external screen refuses to reposition its x position appropriately, even after many attempts. I can't even move it to the right, it simply doesn't move at all:

```bsh
❯ wh setupScreens
/home/janek/.local/bin/setupScreens: ASCII text
   1 #connected=$(xrandr | grep ' connected ')
   2 #k4=$(xrandr | grep '3840' | cut -d' ' -f1)
   3 #k2=$(xrandr | grep '1920' | cut -d' ' -f1)
   4 k4=$(xrandr | grep -1 '   3840' | grep ' connected ' | cut -d' ' -f1)
   5 k2=$(xrandr | grep -1 '   1920' | grep ' connected ' | cut -d' ' -f1)
   6 
   7 #xrandr --output $dp --auto --output $hdmi --mode 1680x1050 --scale 2x2 --right-of $dp && xrandr --output $hdmi --mode 1920x1
     080
   8 xrandr --output $k4 --auto --scale 1x1 --pos 3841x0 --output $k2 --auto --scale 2x2 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 0x0
   9  #--fb 7681x2160
  10 #xrandr --output $dp --auto --scale 0.5x0.5 --output $hdmi --scale 1x1 --mode 1920x1080 --fb 5760x1080 --right-of $dp
❯ xrandr | grep ' connected '
HDMI-0 connected 3840x2160+1810+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 600mm x 340mm panning 5871x2170+1810+0 tracking 7681x2170+0+0 border 0/0/0/0
eDP-1-1 connected primary 3840x2160+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
❯ edbin setupScreens
❯ setupScreens
❯ xrandr --output HDMI-0 --pos 0x0
❯ xrandr | grep ' connected '
HDMI-0 connected 3840x2160+1810+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 600mm x 340mm panning 5871x2170+1810+0 tracking 7681x2170+0+0 border 0/0/0/0
eDP-1-1 connected primary 3840x2160+3841+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
```

Comment: 1. Please include your normal `xrandr` output in your post before custom opts (reset both screens). The script failure may be related to configured mode names, as any error in the `xrandr` will result in failure. 2. Not aware of `grep -1` option  3. Don't use both `--auto` and `--mode` for the same display in the same `xrandr` command, as `--auto` means  "turn on, at preferred res/dpi" while `--mode` sets custom res. 4. Start with `xrandr --output HDMI-0 --off && xrandr --output HDMI-0 --auto --left-of eDP-1-1`or better yet `sudo apt install arandr` and test positioning with the gui.

Comment: Thanks :) 
**(1)** I'll add that - but the script doesn't fail, I checked the exit code!
**(2)** adds context - equaivalent to `--context=1` 
**(3)** Yes, I usually didn't use `auto`, this was for debugging. Doesn't make a difference 
**(4)** arandr errors with `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'screenlayout'` and I want it automated without any GUI application
positioning with the Plasma GUI worked, but there's no scale then.

Comment: How to I reset both screeens? With `auto`?